# Remove duplicate from one array1 to array2

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I Have two arrays in angularjs like.

`$scope.array1 = ["ID","Name","Brand","State"];
$scope.array2 = ["ID","Name","Brand","State","created_by","approved_by","date"];`

I want output like below:

```
$scope.array3 = ["created_by","approved_by","date"];
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Use filter() and includes() functions in javascript to solve your issue

```
$scope.array1 = ["ID","Name","Brand","State"];
$scope.array2 = ["ID","Name","Brand","State","created_by","approved_by","date"];
$scope.array3 = array2.filter(s => !array1.includes(s));
console.log($scope.array3);
```

You can try this. this may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your second array using `.filter()` and `.includes()`:

```js
let array1 = ["ID","Name","Brand","State"];
let array2 = ["ID","Name","Brand","State","created_by","approved_by","date"];

let result = array2.filter(s => !array1.includes(s));

console.log(result);
```